# forward declaration of typedef class

Tags: c++, typedef

For example we have some class with its ptr `typedef`ed

```
class Foo
{
    ....
};
typedef shared_ptr<Foo> FooPtr;
```

Is it possible to forward declare `FooPtr`? The purpose would be to avoid including the header with the `FooPtr` definition.

**Update 1**
Code I tried
**another.h**

```
class FooPtr;
calss A
{
    .....
    FooPtr m_pFoo;
    .....
}
```

compiler error

```
Foo.h: error C2371: 'FooPtr' : redefinition; different basic types
1>         another.h(7) : see declaration of 'FooPtr'
```

Comment: Did you try to experiment with that? What *problem*, if any, are you facing?

Comment: Pointer declarations doesn't need the full type, that goes for both the old "normal" pointers as for the new "smart" pointers.

Comment: @Nawaz I've updated question with my code example and problem I'm faced with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it should be totally possible, because `shared_ptr` is designed to be safe version of a **pointer** and pointers to incomplete types are allowed (just like references).

So yes, you can remove this dependency and replace body of `Foo` (or include of its header) with simple forward declaration:

```
class Foo;
typedef shared_ptr<Foo> FooPtr;
```

Comment: The complete solution for me was: Create a header FooCommon where using such forward declarations Ptrs are typedefined. Include this header in headers where they are used and include to cpp file implementaion of ptr witch are used.

Answer (score 4):

You can't forward declare a `typedef`.

But you can declare it with just a forward declaration of `Foo`.

```
class Foo;
typedef shared_ptr<Foo> FooPtr;
```